# Spring from scratch - Bug on context:property-placeholder

Tags: java, spring

I'm doing some test on a *very, very simple application* using *Spring*.

My app have only have **one bean** and I'm injecting a simple **String** to this class and printing this value. **So far all working**.

---

## What I need:

I want to get this String from a configuration file, so I create the file inside */src/main/resource*

**What I did:**

**1)** On my *application-context.xml* I add:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myConfigFile.properties" />
```

**2)** On my *application-context.xml* I change from the simple String to use ${name_test}:

```
<bean id="hello" class="com.dummy.SayHello">
    <property name="name" value="${name_test}" />
</bean>
```

**3)** I double check *myConfigFile.properties* and contains the "name_test=JackTheRipper"

**4)** But my output is not 'translating' the value from the config file, I have this output when I run my app:

```
Hello ${name_test}
```

**And I'm stuck here, any clue, tips???**

---

**Just FYI**

- I use [THIS](http://pookey.co.uk/wordpress/archives/50-getting-started-with-maven-and-spring) **tutorial** for my tests, maybe could help.
- I add the log4j maven dependencies and log4j config file and all works fine! So Spring and log4j are finding the files inside "src/main/resource"
- I'm using **maven**, and to run my app, I'm using:

> mvn clean compile exec:java
>
> ---

## SOLUTION EXPLANATION:

The root cause was how I was getting the *application-context.xml* on my java class.

I was doing:

```
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("application-context.xml"));
```

and then after this post I change it to:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
```

- A good place to understand and read is [HERE](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory)
- Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Are 1) and 2) placed in the same file?

Comment: @axtavt - Yes step 1 and 2 were done on application-context.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem I can imagine here is that you use `BeanFactory` instead of `ApplicationContext`. Compared to `ApplicationContext`, `BeanFactory` misses some advanced features including automatic registration of postprocessors, that is necessary for `<context:property-placeholder>`.

Comment: This question could be stupid, but how can I confirm that I'm running with ApplicationContext or BeanFactory? Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Castanho: It depends on the way how you instantiate Spring container, as something like `XmlBeanFactory` or as something like `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext`.

Comment: @axtavt, I'm using: BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(
          new ClassPathResource("application-context.xml"));

Comment: @Castanho: That's the cause. Use `ApplicationContext ctx = ClasspathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml")`, also see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory

Comment: @axtavt: Ahaaaa..... I think you are 100% correct, I'll check when I get on home! And I'll let you know my finds! Thanks again axtavt

Comment: @axtavt - Checked here, all works now!! Thanks for your time, I raise on up for you and mark as "accepted answer"

Answer (score 1):

Just for curiosity sake, instead of using `<context:property-placeholder>`, can you try this?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:myConfigFile.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If that doesn't work, try putting a `*` after `classpath`:-

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:myConfigFile.properties" />
```

Comment: same output for both scenarios. I've tried before adding the * after the classpath. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I just check on the log: "Neither XML 'id' nor 'name' specified - using generated bean name [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0]"

Answer (score 1):

Your config is fine. My guess is that your properties file cannot be found on the classpath. Is there any Spring logging in regards to the configurer? Try running:

`mvn clean install exec:java`

This will create an artifact (jar), which will bundle your `src/main/resources` content, while compile obviously just compiles the source files to class files.

I might try a test case too. Add spring test to your pom:

**POM**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>[YOUR SPRING VERSION]</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:application-context.xml")
public class TestSayHello
{
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("hello")
   private SayHello hello;

   @Test
   public void testSayHello()
   {
      Assert.assertNotNull(hello);
      Assert.assertEquals("JackTheRipper", hello.getName());
   }
}
```

The no id or name message is just a warning since your bean doesn't contain either. If your config file could not be found, you should a message stating so as well.

Comment: I develop here you tip on test, and is working! Thanks! One Up for you!